# i am trying to write a simple textbox (for people to type url in it) with a button in html

Tags: javascript, web-applications, web

i am trying to write a simple textbox (for people to type url in it) with a button in html. 
when the button is clicked, it will send the url of the current website that I am browsing to the url that is listed in the textbox using the POST method. is it possible?
i have been looking on forums but don't really know which is the right one cos it seems that there are various way of doing it and i don't really know how to edit them.

my current code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>YouTube</title>

<script type="javascript/text">

function handleButtonEnterClick(tab) {
//TODO:
    var textbox_url = document.getElementById("url_textbox");
    var textbox_value = textbox_url.value; //eg. value = "www.google.com"

       //Need to have a POST method written here to send the url of the current 
       //webpage for example www.youtube.com to url listed in the textbox, 
       //for example www.google.com
       //May I know how can I do it? Thanks.
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id ="container">
<p>Enter URL:</p>
<input type="text" id="url_textbox" name="url_textbox" />
<input type="button" id="button_enter" name="button_enter" 
       value="enter" onclick="handleButtonEnter" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will there be a page redirect when the form is submitted or is this gong to use ajax? (i.e no page refresh. Send the data in the background)

Comment: Umm... I'm confused as to what you want this code to do:  If you want a textarea for a human to enter any arbitrary destination URL to send the current location data to, how do you know anything is connected at that URL listening for the data? How would this be used, by whom, and why?

Comment: Regarding your flag, I'm asking a Dev to take a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>YouTube</title>

    <script type="javascript/text">

      function handleButtonEnterClick(tab) 
      {
        var textbox_url = document.getElementById("url_textbox");
        var textbox_value = textbox_url.value; //eg. value = "www.google.com"

        //Set the form action to the textbox value
        var the_form = document.getElementById("the_form");
        the_form.setAttribute("action", textbox_value);

        //Set the value of the url field to the current url
        document.getElementById("url").setAttribute("value", window.location);

        the_form.submit();
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id ="container">
      <form action="" method="post" id="the_form">
        <p>Enter URL:</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" />
        <input type="text" id="url_textbox" name="url_textbox" />
        <input type="button" id="button_enter" name="button_enter" 
          value="enter" onclick="handleButtonEnter" />
      </form>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's not whatshc has asked. It's the other way around. The URL in the textbox is to be the target. And the current page is to be the URL that gets sent

Comment: Doh, it's been a long day - will redo my answer.

Comment: Indeed, however, your answer still doesn't submit the current URL... I suggest you integrate Paul's answer (window.location.href) and set the value of a hidden element in the form

Comment: @Brendan Bullen Just spotted I missed that bit. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a `<form>` element, which a) has `action` attribute to indicate where to send the data; b) on submit sends the data (I've added an extra `<input type='hidden'>` to store your current pages url for sending).

```
<script type="javascript/text">    
    function handleButtonEnterClick() {
        var textbox_value = document.getElementById("url_textbox").value;
        document.getElementById('myUrl').value = window.location;
        var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
        form.action = textbox_value;
        form.submit();
    }
</script>

<div id="container">
    <form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
        <p>Enter URL:</p>
        <input type="hidden" id="myUrl" name="url" />
        <input type="text" id="url_textbox" name="url_textbox" />
        <input type="button" id="button_enter" name="button_enter" 
               value="enter" onclick="handleButtonEnter" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The current page location is stored in the JavaScript variable "window.location.href" (thats in Chrome, might be different elsewhere).

You also need to set the action of your form to the URL in the textarea. Suggest you put an id tag on the html form element, and use that id tag to set the action property of the form to the contents of the textbox as part part of the buttons onclick handler.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

- Use a HTML form, as [Ant has shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226176/i-am-trying-to-write-a-simple-textbox-for-people-to-type-url-in-it-with-a-butto/6226222#6226222), set the *action* and *method* attributes. Add a *submit* button inside the form (along with your textbox). When you click on the Submit button, your data will get posted.
- Use AJAX to post your form if you want to stay in the current page